# How can I end the user conversation or session using Microsoft bot framework version 4 if the chatbot is idle for a few minutes?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I've created a bot using Microsoft bot framework version 4 (in C#) and I am using the conversation ID to maintain state with my back end conversation engine.

What is the best approach to end the conversation through the direct line channel if the chatbot is idle for a few minutes?